# how to save 4 bytes emoji into mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, emoji, utf8mb4

**mysql version** 5.5.41 (MariaDB)

```
ALTER TABLE msg_ms CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;
```

I have convert my table into utf8mb4 but my col (msg_desc) data still showing ???? when I try to save 4 bytes emoji. How to solve this problem?

```
CREATE TABLE `msg_ms` (
  `msg_desc` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL
   PRIMARY KEY (`msg_code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin
```

Comment: "data still showing ????" - showing where? In db editor, on page?